# Google Analytics timingVar

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I have a react application which is integrated with google analytics (GA). We re piloting this integration to collect the user behaviour in different scenarios following the guides from GA. As an example we have an external link in one of our pages which will take users to a different application. On clicking this line we are firing two GA functions. One is to record the click event and the other is to find the time the user spent on the base page before clicking the link. We can see the click event in the GA but not able to see the timing variable.

In the console we can see the GA calls like :

```
[react-ga] called ga('send', fieldObject);
log.js:2 [react-ga] with fieldObject:{"hitType":"event","eventCategory":"ExternalLink","eventAction":"Clicked","eventLabel":"Acme-Web"}
log.js:2 [react-ga] called ga('send', fieldObject);
log.js:2 [react-ga] with fieldObject: {"hitType":"timing","timingCategory":"ExternalLink","timingVar":"timeSpent","timingValue":17432,"timingLabel":"Acme-Web"}
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: a [sampleRate](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sampleRate) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings#sampling_considerations) there are sample rates that are applied to timing Hits.

[image]

This means that if you don't have enough pageviews you will only see 100 timing hits and even if you have many pageviews timing hits will be capped at around 10,000 / day or 1% of pageviews.

This means that timing events are pretty unreliable for most use cases. You should instead fire a second event with a Value attached to it.